# C++ Array of random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, random, srand

I have a bit of a problem with this. I've tried to create a function to return a random number and pass it to the array, but for some reason, all the numbers generated are "0".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int generLosNum(int);


int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int LosNum;
    const int rozmiar = 10;
    int tablica[rozmiar];

    for(int i=0; i<rozmiar; i++)
    {
        tablica[i] = generLosNum(LosNum);
        cout << tablica[i] <<"  ";
    }
return 0;
}
int generLosNum(int LosNum)
{
    int LosowyNum;           
    LosowyNum = (rand() % 10);         
    return (LosNum);
}
```

Comment: You're returning `LosNum`, the value you passed in, not the random number.

Comment: Also, `generLosNum` doesn't need any parameter. Passing irrelevant arguments is not a mistake (except for impairing readability), but if you didn't do that in the first place, you wouldn't make that typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the return for your **int generLosNum(int LosNum)** was printing  0 because you had it returning LosNum which was initialized equaling to zero. I changed your code so it works and will print out the 10 random numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int generLosNum();


int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    int LosNum = 0;
    const int rozmiar = 10;
    int tablica[rozmiar];

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
    {
        tablica[i] = generLosNum();
        cout << tablica[i] << "  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
int generLosNum()
{
    int LosowyNum;
    LosowyNum = (rand() % 10);
    return LosowyNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method `generLosNum` to the following and the method signature to `int generLosNum()` and it should work.

```
int generLosNum()
{
    return (rand() % 10);
}
```

**Reason**: As others also mentioned in the comments, you were just returning the number that you passed in as parameter and also the logic for this method doesn't even need a parameter.